# Как отследить все исходящие http запросы в Node.Js?

Tags: node.js

Есть программа на node.js в ней много-много кода, и много разных модулей.
Эта программа отправляет множество http запросов по разным адресам.

В какой-то момент она начинает слать столько запросов, что виснет сервер.
Проблема уже найдена и был поставлен таймаут для этих запросов.

Но есть чувство, что запросы могут начать отсылаться циклом в каком-нибудь другом месте.

Мой вопрос: можно ли как-то мониторить или логировать ВСЕ исходящие запросы из node.js приложения?

Comment: `tcpdump`, исходящий трафик по 80 порту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [global-request-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-request-logger). Будет перехватывать все http и https запросы, которые были отправлены с помощью стандартных [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) и [https](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html).